# How to import nanoid package from npm to Laravels?

Tags: laravel, npm-package, nanoid

I will use unique number using nanoid package from nodejs to laravels,
but i get error this.

this is mycontroller.

```
     <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use DateTime;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    
    
    class BooksController extends Controller
    {
        public function addBooks(Request $request)
        {
            $data =([
                'id' = nanoid(16);
                'name'= $request->input('bookName');
                'year'= $request->input('tahunT');
                'author'= $request->input('author');
                'summary'= $request->input('publishers');
                'publisher'= $request->input('pageCount');
                'pageCount' = $request->input('ReadPage');
                'readPage'= $request->input('');
                'finished' = $pageCount == $readPage ? true : false;
                'reading' = $readPage > 0 ? true : false;
                'insertedAt'= new DateTime();
                'updatedAt'= $insertedAt; 
    
        }
}
```

this is my app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
const { nanoid } = require('nanoid');
```

when I use the nanoid, error like this

[image]

syntax error, unexpected '=' , expecting ']'.
What I should to do? or you can give the other opinion to generate unique number?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use it in plain PHP, you are confusing NPM (JavaScript) with Laravel (PHP).

Comment: Then, do you have any solution to generate unique number?

Comment: @ShabrinaNurdianiS [`Str::uuid()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-uuid) or even [`Str::random()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-random)

Comment: Is if using str::random() possibly get the same number? Cause it is random, so i think it possible to get same number.